# Google App : More than one HTML or script file in the same App Project?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a fairly seasoned web developer, so the Google Web framework with Google App Scripts looks just right for me. Unfortunately, I don't get very far before I hit a wall. Here is the largest one (right now).

Scenario: Develop a simple app to solve some a few of the programming problems I always use when I approach a new language. Put each problem on a separate page. Put the css and javascript in separate files.

This works fine initially. The first problem is a statistical mean of means problem. I found their starter template for reading data from a spreadsheet, modified the template to show the data, and went from there. CSS was simple and included in the file. It only required the initial index.html and code.gs.

But now, I want to modify index.html to add links to call OTHER HTML files, which the App project cheerfully helps me to add. I can add more .gs files as well. Great, I think. But HOW do I call them? A link requires a URL, but the only one I have is to the project. As far as I can tell, there is no way to reference a file included in the same project. I can call a function in some other library but not on another page of this one. The .gs scripts look to be serverside code. What do I do with and access client side javascript files. Or CSS files?

I found this on your site but I don't have a clue how to actually use it.
[Use project Javascript and CSS files in a Google Apps Script web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344167/use-project-javascript-and-css-files-in-a-google-apps-script-web-app).

I've searched and searched for answers to these questions and have found very little with a real working project example.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to do a similar thing to me. Basically I need a system that allows you to login then provide additional data once you have logged in. So I started out with a basic form and then hit the wall that you are talking about, where it seems to be impossible to load HTML pages.

I then noticed that you CAN send back strings, therefore you can put that string into a div(see `loadPage()`), therefore show different pages. Below is a simple example, including handling failures. You can then keep writing pages as you would expect. So you can pass values to the next form and the next to produce an application.

To use this, you can enter in any username and it will fail, showing up a thrown error message. If you type in `fuzzyjulz` as the username it with show the next page including additional information from the login process.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Main')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function onLogin(form) {
  if (form.username == "fuzzyjulz") {
    var template =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Response');

    //Setup any variables that should be used in the page
    template.firstName = "Fuzzy";
    template.username = form.username;

    return template.evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
      .getContent();
  } else {
    throw "You could not be found in the database please try again.";
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename)
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .getContent();
 }
```

**Main.html**

```
<?!= include('CSS'); ?>
<script>
  function loadPage(htmlOut) {
    var div = document.getElementById('content');
    div.innerHTML = htmlOut;
    document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = "";
  }
  function onFailure(error) {
    var errors = document.getElementById('errors');
    errors.innerHTML = error.message;
  }
</script>
<div id="errors"></div>
<div id="content">
  <?!= include('Login'); ?>
</div>
```

**CSS.html**

```
<style>
  p b {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```

**Login.html**

```
<script>
  function onLoginFailure(error) {
    var loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');
    loginBtn.disabled = false;
    loginBtn.value = 'Login';
    onFailure(error);
  }
</script>
<div class="loginPanel">
  <form>
    <p>
      <b>Username: </b>
      <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="loginBtn" value="Login" onclick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Loading...';google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(loadPage)
      .withFailureHandler(onLoginFailure)
      .onLogin(this.parentNode)"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Response.html**

```
<div class="text">
  Hi <?= firstName ?>,<br/>
  Thanks for logging in as <?= username ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this FuzzyJulz, just what I needed. (Google Sites broke my javascript password approach)