# HTMLservice dialogue box not displaying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have only recently started playing around with Google-Apps-Scripts. I wanted to see if I could add a timeline to the top of my Google-Sheet dashboard using a 3rd party JS library.

My goal is to add the timeline widget inside of a Dialog box. I manage to get my dialogue box showing but with no content. I hope that what I am trying to do is possible. I'm aware that I could create a website and embed Google Doc inside it but wanted to try this, just for fun.

1) create the Dialog box on sheet open:

```
function onOpen() {
 var htmlOutput = 
     HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('cabbages')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
     .setWidth(1500)
     .setHeight(600);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'bla');
}
```

2) cabbages file to show the timeline based on a library:

```
  <div>
  <script>
  function getContent(css, js) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(css).getRawContent();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(js).getRawContent();
     }
     getContent(timeLineCSS,timeLineJS);
</script>

  <div id="mytimeline"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
    var container = document.getElementById('mytimeline');

    // Create a DataSet with data (enables two way data binding)
    var data = new vis.DataSet([
      {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
      {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14'},
      {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
      {id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-04-19'},
      {id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
      {id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-27'}
    ]);

    // Configuration for the Timeline
    var options = {};

    // Create a Timeline
    var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);
  </script>
  </div>
```

To link to the timeline library JS and CSS files I followed the post here:[Use project Javascript and CSS files in a Google Apps Script web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344167/use-project-javascript-and-css-files-in-a-google-apps-script-web-app)

I went with the top voted answer not the chosen answer.

So I have 2 other "html" files in my app script library:

timeLineJS:

```
<script>
// lots and lots of JS here
</script>
```

timeLineCSS

```
<style>
// lots of CSS here.
</style>
```

I now refresh the sheet and the dialog appears but with no content. Here is a screen shot of the console when I right click on the dialog box:
[image]

You can see "mytimeline" div and the content of "cabbages" file. But the dialog box is empty.

All I can think of is that the JS and CSS are not loading in via the links. Does Google-Apps-Script have an issue with loading in external files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using NATIVE instead of IFRAME for now.

Apparently it's pretty buggy ATM, a good portion of my scripts are behaving erradically with IFRAME.

Edit:
Just fiddled a little with your code. Google does have external limitation because of safety concerns, it's name is caja, and you can test if your code is gonna work correctly with it here:

https://caja.appspot.com/

Aparently vis.js doesn't play nice with it.

Comment: So just replace IFRAME with NATIVE?